# How to prevent FF4 popup menu from being transparent?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4

I develop "Hebrew Calendar extension" (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefo ... -calendar/) and under FF4 extension shows transparent popup menu

[image]

Could you help me to understand how to fix the issue.

Thank you,
Igor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [menupopup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/menupopup) not [popup](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL%3apopup)